# Unity : 30fps vs 60fps on 30fps animation

Tags: animation, mobile, unity-game-engine, frame-rate

I'm testing this on mobile, i have a 30 frame animation with 30 frame rate, i build it to my mobile with in-game target frame rate of 30 and 60. since the animation frame rate would be time base in unity, the animation would be exactly 1 second on both build.

This is what i assume would happen :

1) on 30fps build, the animation would play 1 frame on each in-game frame, so it would be 1 second.

2) on 60fps build, the animation would play 1 frame on every 2 in-game frame, so it would be 1 second as well.

My question is, why would the 60fps build look better compare with 30fps build? since the animation would just play 30 frame throughout 1 second.

There aren't anything else in the scene, only the animation, so nothing else would distract the feeling of 60fps would look better.

hope you all can understand the question, and if anyone have the same feeling, or you can test it yourself to see if you feel the same, feel free to comment, answer or discuss. Thanks.

Comment: **on 60fps build, the animation would play 2 frame on each in-game frame, so it would be 1 second as well.** How would this be 1 second as well??

Comment: sorry that's a typo, i'll edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think i might have the answer, that's because since the animation would be time base, unity would fill better on empty keyframe in 60fps. example : set a position keyframe on 1st frame, then set another position key frame at 30th frame, unity would effectively play this as a 60 frame rate animation since there are so many empty keyframe.

I'm not sure if this is the exact answer, if someone can confirm this or there are no other answer i'll rate this as answer.

Comment: yes i think you are right, unless you are swapping out sprites as in a 2d game with a sprite sheet. If you are moving gameobjects then it will appear smoother.

Comment: Almost correct! :)

Unity3D uses interpolation between keyframes, and it'll calculate the exact value (position, scale, color...) depending on the animation curve between the keyframes.
https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2015/02/curves_mode_ex.png

Therefore, the more FPS per second, the more values Unity3D will interpolate between keyframes, making the animation smoother :)

Answer (score 1):

I find the question very vague and lacking specifics of what kind of animation is being discussed and *how* it is being used. 2D or 3D? Sprites or geometry? Frames of bitmap graphics or tweened motion created within Unity?

**As an example**: If your animation was a bitmap sprite animation and the sprite did not ever change coordinate positions, then 30 frames of bitmap animation played over a time duration of 1 second would appear EXACTLY THE SAME in a 60fps build as it would in a 30fps build.

If you're also moving the sprite from one XY to another set of XY, then the MOTION would appear smoother in the 60fps build due to interpolation of the coordinate positions (as you said in your own answer). But your bitmap frames still are playing exactly the same (1 image per 1/30ths of a second).

Similarly, if the animation discussed here is geometry, then everything is based on interpolation of the shapes and thus yes, 60 fps allows for 60 unique frames of animation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15339674)

Comment: @DougStevenson: Don't be distracted by the first paragraph, the rest of the answer is quite informative.

Comment: @DougStevenson The answer is in paragraphs 2, 3 and 4.